# Select distinct values based on multiple column from table

Tags: sql

I am having below dummy table

```
select * from (
select 'A' as col1, 'B' as col2 from dual 
union
select 'B' as col1, 'A' as col2 from dual 
union
select 'A' as col1, 'C' as col2 from dual 
union
select 'C' as col1, 'A' as col2 from dual 
union
select 'A' as col1, 'D' as col2 from dual 
)a
```

which will give output as below

```
col1 col2
A   B
A   C
A   D
B   A
C   A
```

I wants to find the distinct values from that table like below

```
col1 col2
A    B
A    C
A    D
```

first row can be A B or B A same as second can be A C or C A

Is it possible??
We got the solution for above problem which is below

```
select distinct least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2)
from the_table;
```

but if there is more than 2 column, then i wouldn't work

Let us assume the below scenario

Input

```
 col1 col2 col3
    A   B   E
    A   C   E
    A   D   E
    B   A   F
    C   A   E
```

Output

```
 col1 col2 col3
    A   B   E
    A   D   E
    B   A   F
    C   A   E
```

then what would be the possible solution ?

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.  Oracle and Postgres are not the same.

Comment: i need answer which will work in all database

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method:

```
select col1, col2
from t
where col1 <= col2
union all
select col1, col2
from t
where col1 > col2 and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col2 and t2.col2 = t.col1);
```

Comment: it's working, let me analyse the query... thnx for quick response :)

Comment: we can also use case statement like "select distinct case when col1<=col2 then col1 else col2 end as least, case when col1<=col2 then col2 else col1 end as greatest from table;" @Gordon Linoff, Can you please help me to find out solution for more than 2 columns

Answer (score 2):

The following will work for Oracle and Postgres:

```
select distinct least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2)
from the_table;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/BZXC69735

Comment: row values may be full word like Apple, Orange... so that wouldn't work in that case

Comment: let me check :) @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @RamanSingh: just add them to the functions: `least(col1, col2, col3)`

Comment: if we have 3 column then we need the show result based on the 3 column and there will be 3 columns in output and least, greatest will give to 2 column only, so that result i can't get from those 2 function:( @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @RamanSingh: you should have included that additional problem in your initial question. Changing the scope of your question once you have an answer is not polite

Comment: should i need to raise new question for this challenge(btw i already mentioned multiple column)@a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136204/discussion-between-raman-singh-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Answer (score 0):

```
    select DISTINCT * from (
select 'A' as col1, 'B' as col2 from dual 
union
select 'B' as col1, 'A' as col2 from dual 
union
select 'A' as col1, 'C' as col2 from dual 
union
select 'C' as col1, 'A' as col2 from dual 
union
select 'A' as col1, 'D' as col2 from dual 
)a
```

Comment: Will return both A,C and C, A.

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1, col2 from t where col1 <= col2
union
select col2, col1 from t where col1 > col2
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @TobySpeight, yes I know... I usually do that, but I had to take the dog out on a walk.